# Cannot import typescript modules inside main.ts on Vue.js app

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, routes

I am building a simple vue.js app using typescript,I am trying to do some routing and bring the route file to `main.ts` but when I run the app I get the following error:

```
These relative modules were not found:

* ./plugins/vuetify in ./src/main.ts
* ./router/routerIndex in ./src/main.ts
* ./store/index in ./src/main.ts
```

---

**main.ts** is in `src/main.ts`

**indexRouter.ts** is in `src/router/indexRoute.ts`

**main.ts**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import App from "./App.vue"
import store from "./store/index";
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import router from "./router/routerIndex"


Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
  router
}).$mount("#app");
```

**routerIndex.ts**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from　"vue-router";
import Home from "../components/pages/Home.vue";


Vue.use(Router);

const routes = [
    {
        name: "home",
        path: "/",
        component: Home
    }
]

const router = new Router({ mode: "history", routes });

export default router;
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES2019",                          
  "module": "commonjs",
  "outDir": "./dist",
  "strict": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
 },
"include": [
      "src/**/*",
      "src/**/*.ts",
      "src/**/*.tsx",
      "src/**/*.vue",
      "tests/**/*.ts",
      "tests/**/*.tsx"
    ],

}
```

This project was not installed with Vue@Cli, it was installed with npm by the person who created the project.

I am new to both `Vue` and `Typescript` so I might be screwing up something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don’t need to use the line Vue.use(VueRouter) twice. Use it once in the ./plugins/indexRouter.ts file

Answer (score 0):

You can install @vue/cli, then open the `vue ui`, import the your project in the vue ui and then using the ui again download typescript plugin. Tell me if anything is unclear:)

Comment: I am afraid that doing a complete reinstall may mess with some files that the backend developer might be using :(, but I am gonna try to make a copy and do it

Comment: uninstalled and then installed typescript again but the error is the same

Comment: Alright, let's try the other option. Try this: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#typescript